# How to resolve this error that nginx-ingress-controller start fail in my k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, rancher

> - Rancher v2.4.2
> - kubernetes version: v1.17.4

In my k8s cluster,nginx-ingress-controller doesn't work and restart always.I don't get anything useful information in the logs, thanks for your help.

cluster nodes:

```
> kubectl get nodes  
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                      AGE   VERSION
master1   Ready    controlplane,etcd,worker   18d   v1.17.4
master2   Ready    controlplane,etcd,worker   17d   v1.17.4
node1     Ready    worker                     17d   v1.17.4
node2     Ready    worker                     17d   v1.17.4
```

cluster pods in ingress-nginx namespace

```
> kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-http-backend-5bb77998d7-k7gdh   1/1     Running   1          17d
nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh          0/1     Running   10         27m
nginx-ingress-controller-bh2pg          1/1     Running   0          63m
nginx-ingress-controller-drtzx          1/1     Running   0          63m
nginx-ingress-controller-qndbw          1/1     Running   0          63m
```

the pod logs of nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh

```
> kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh -n ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       nginx-0.25.1-rancher1
  Build:         
  Repository:    https://github.com/rancher/ingress-nginx.git
  nginx version: openresty/1.15.8.1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

>
```

describe info

```
> kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh -n ingress-nginx
Name:         nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh
Namespace:    ingress-nginx
Priority:     0
Node:         node2/172.26.13.11
Start Time:   Tue, 19 Apr 2022 07:12:16 +0000
Labels:       app=ingress-nginx
              controller-revision-hash=758cb9dbbc
              pod-template-generation=8
Annotations:  cattle.io/timestamp: 2022-04-19T07:08:51Z
              field.cattle.io/ports:
                [[{"containerPort":80,"dnsName":"nginx-ingress-controller-hostport","hostPort":80,"kind":"HostPort","name":"http","protocol":"TCP","source...
              field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:
                [{"addresses":["172.26.13.130"],"nodeId":"c-wv692:m-d5802d05bbf0","port":80,"protocol":"TCP"},{"addresses":["172.26.13.130"],"nodeId":"c-w...
              prometheus.io/port: 10254
              prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:       Running
IP:           172.26.13.11
IPs:
  IP:           172.26.13.11
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/nginx-ingress-controller
Containers:
  nginx-ingress-controller:
    Container ID:  docker://09a6248edb921b9c9cbab678c793fe1cc3d28322ea6abbb8f15c899351ce4b40
    Image:         172.26.13.133:5000/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.25.1-rancher1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://172.26.13.133:5000/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:fe50ceea3d1a0bc9a7ccef8d5845c9a30b51f608e411467862dff590185a47d2
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:    80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
      --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
      --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
      --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
      --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    143
      Started:      Tue, 19 Apr 2022 07:40:12 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 19 Apr 2022 07:41:32 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  11
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=60s timeout=20s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=60s timeout=20s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  ingress-nginx (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from nginx-ingress-serviceaccount-token-2kdbj (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  nginx-ingress-serviceaccount-token-2kdbj:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  nginx-ingress-serviceaccount-token-2kdbj
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     :NoExecute
                 :NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>           default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress-controller-6l4jh to node2
  Normal   Pulled     27m (x3 over 30m)   kubelet, node2     Container image "172.26.13.133:5000/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.25.1-rancher1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    27m (x3 over 30m)   kubelet, node2     Created container nginx-ingress-controller
  Normal   Started    27m (x3 over 30m)   kubelet, node2     Started container nginx-ingress-controller
  Normal   Killing    27m (x2 over 28m)   kubelet, node2     Container nginx-ingress-controller failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  Unhealthy  25m (x10 over 29m)  kubelet, node2     Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.26.13.11:10254/healthz: dial tcp 172.26.13.11:10254: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  10m (x21 over 29m)  kubelet, node2     Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.26.13.11:10254/healthz: dial tcp 172.26.13.11:10254: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    8s (x69 over 20m)   kubelet, node2     Back-off restarting failed container
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ingress controller pod fails the liveness/readiness checks but looks like only on a certain node. You could try:

- check the node for firewall on that port
- update to newer version than nginx-0.25.1

Comment: I didn't even turn on the firewall，and the version of nginx-ingress  is controlled by Rancher, I don't know how to change it.